# How define an Interface with Optional values, but one of them Mandatory - TypeScript

Tags: typescript, interface, option-type

How can I define a TypeScript Interface that has a few **Optional** values, BUT one (or more) of them is **Mandatory** ???

Let's say I have the following code:

```
interface ISearchKey
{
  name?: string;
  id?: number;
}

function findItem(search: ISearchKey): Item 
{
  // ... 

  return ...
}
```

and I would like the object that implements the `ISearchKey` interface, to have a "name" value and/or an "id" value. One of them ("name" and "id") can be emitted, but not both!

I know I can solve this by validating the input inside the `findItem()` function:

```
let name = search.name || "";
let id   = search.id   || -1;
```

or any other type of input validation, but can this be done using TypeScript *type validation*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Union the types, e.g.

```
type ISearchKey = { name: string } | { id: number }

const test = (key: ISearchKey) => console.log(key);

test({ name: "name" });
test({ id: 12 });
test({ name: "name", id: 12 });
test({ fail: true }); // Errors
```

For required properties, you can intersect:

```
// With mandatory data
type ISearchKey2 = ({ name: string } | { id: number }) & { data: any };

const test2 = (key: ISearchKey2) => console.log(key);

test2({ name: "name" }); // Error
test2({ name: "name", data: 0 });
test2({ id: 12 }); // Error
test2({ id: 12, data: 1 });
test2({ name: "name", id: 12 }); // Error
test2({ name: "name", id: 12, data: 2 });
test2({ fail: true }); // Still Errors
```

---

As **@jcalz** noted, these unions allow for different typing of the other property, as long as one of the properties is there, e.g.

```
{ name: "name", id: "not a number!" }
```

A more correct type union would be:

```
{name: string, id?: number} | {name?: string, id: number}
```

This will retain the correct type of the optional properties.

Comment: What is the "type" keyword? How is it different from an "interface"? How to use it with always-mandatory data e.g: `{ id?: number; name?: string; data: any } /* data is always mandatory */`

Comment: `type` mainly used for type aliasing and combining. It's fairly similar to an interface definition.

Comment: @GilEpshtain: Glad it helped :)

Comment: I would suggest something like `{name: string, id?: number} | {name?: string, id: number}`, because just `{name: string} | {id: number}` will allow presumably undesirable values like `{name: 'okay', id: 'whoops'}`